# How do I convert image data from JSON String?

Tags: xcode, uiimage, nsdata

I'm trying to load an image into a tableview cell.
The code is OK, except it doesn't like images from a NSString - which is understandable!

How do I a) Load images from mySQL database - do I save them in the database as links to the Image folder of the website i.e. the path?
And b) I'm loading the data as a JSON string to NSString.
How do I convert the image part, to UIImage?
My code is below - everything runs OK, except the image part, of course.
Do I use NSData to convert?
Many thanks in advance.
@implementation ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CarsRUs.png"]];
    [self.listTableView setBackgroundView:imageView];    // Set this view controller object as the delegate and data source for the table view
    self.listTableView.delegate = self;
    self.listTableView.dataSource = self;

    // Create array object and assign it to _feedItems variable
    _feedItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    // Create new HomeModel object and assign it to _homeModel variable
    _homeModel = [[HomeModel alloc] init];

    // Set this view controller object as the delegate for the home model object
    _homeModel.delegate = self;

    // Call the download items method of the home model object
    [_homeModel downloadItems];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items
{
    // This delegate method will get called when the items are finished downloading

    // Set the downloaded items to the array
    _feedItems = items;

    // Reload the table view
    [self.listTableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of feed items (initially 0)
    return _feedItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Retrieve cell
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // Get the location to be shown
    Location *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];

    // Get references to labels of cell
    myCell.textLabel.text = item.address;
    myCell.detailTextLabel.text = item.name;
    myCell.imageView.image = item.image;
    return myCell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Set selected location to var
    _selectedLocation = _feedItems[indexPath.row];

    // Manually call segue to detail view controller
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];
}


#pragma mark Segue

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    DetailViewController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;

    // Set the property to the selected location so when the view for
    // detail view controller loads, it can access that property to get the feeditem obj
    detailVC.selectedLocation = _selectedLocation;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

A) depends on the size of the imge, i think. bigger files are preferrably stored in the filesystem, with links in the db. for smaller images you can get away with storing them in the database directly. This is a good referene: http://www.sourcecodester.com/article/other/should-i-save-images-database-or-file-system.html

B)NSData is the way to go:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithUTF8String:myJsonString];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```